# XSLT: Move node one level up

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to know how to move nodes up one level using XSLT if certain conditions are complied. To give you an example have a look at the following XML source:

```
<Settings>
  <String [...]>
    <Boolean [...]/>
  </String>
</Settings>
```

That is the XML I have as starting situation. To be clear, the node names "Settings", "String", "Boolean" are special nodes we defined.

The problem is that "Boolean" nodes are not allowed inside of "String" nodes. That's why I have to move those "Boolean" nodes on level up. The desired XML would look like this:

```
<Settings>
  <String [...]></String>
  <Boolean [...]/>
</Settings>
```

The XSLT also has to work with every String node which has a sibling Boolean node, regardless of the position in the XML-tree.

So far I learned that you have to first copy all of your XML using a "identity rule" and then apply some special rules for the desired transformations:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"        
  xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">

  <!-- Identity rule -->
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- special rules ... -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The thing I am struggling with is the rule to move all "Boolean" nodes which are siblings of "String" nodes one level up. How can I do that?!?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a variation of the "override the identity rule" design pattern -- I have provided a slightly more accurate override. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My interpretation of the requirement gives the solution as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="String">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::Boolean)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Boolean"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you Michael. Your answer seems to work fine. Only would only propose one minor change:

<xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::Boolean)]"/>

becomes

<xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::Boolean)] | @*"/>

With this change the attributes of the String nodes get copied too. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
<!-- copy all -->
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- ignore booleans-inside-strings -->
<xsl:template match="String/Boolean" />

<!-- place the booleans-inside-strings into the settings element -->
<xsl:template match="Settings">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="//String/Boolean" />
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why not `match="@* | node()"` and `select="@* | node()"` in your "copy all" template? Just curious ...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That works fine for my example. But it won't work always, since it always copies the Boolean node into the settings element. The rule should copy the Boolean element one level up. Think of <Settings><X><String><Boolean/></String></X></Settings>

That should transform to: <Settings><X><String></String><Boolean/></X></Settings>

Comment: Also, why the starting `//` in `//String/Boolean`?

Answer (score 3):

This solution is quite similar to that of @Michae-Kay. However, the overriding of the identity rule is a little bit more precise -- only `String` elements that really have a `Boolean` child are matched:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="String[Boolean]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::Boolean)]|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Boolean"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied against the following XML document**:

```
<Settings>
    <String>
        <Boolean />
    </String>
    <String/>
</Settings>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<Settings>
   <String/>
   <Boolean/>
   <String/>
</Settings>
```

Comment: could you also take a look at my answer? I can't find a mistake there worth downvoting. I don't care about downvote itself, just want to see if I missed some blunder.

Comment: @Flack: I think your solution is OK. You only need to apply templates to the attributes of `Setings` -- otherwise they will be lost. I have upvoted your answer, but please, add this recommended fix, too.

Comment: It was a conscious omission, due to the OP's provided sample. Though I chose to remove my answer as there are two which are better designed. Upvote in return of course. Was waiting for respawn of available votes.